# How to cast a generic type to primitive type

Tags: generics, rust, casting, primitive-types

I am newbye with Rust. I don't know how to cast generic type `<T>` to primitive type.

There is a tiny example a function sum with generic types:

```rust
fn sum<T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>, U>(x:T, y: U) -> T {
    // is there any line of code similar to:
    // x + y as T
    
    x + y as T
    
    // or check the type
    // match type(x) {
    //    i32 => x + y as i32,
    //    i64 => x + y as i64,
    //    f32 => x + y as f32,
    //    _ => 0
    // }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 22.22;
    println!("{}", sum(a, b));
    
    let a = 11.11;
    let b = 2;
    println!("{}", sum(a, b));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code snippet which direction you need the conversion to work. If you want to cast a primitive type (e.g. `u32`) to `T`, you can add `+ From<u32>` to trait bounds of `T`, and use `let x: T = some_u32_value.into()`. If you want to cast `T` to a primitive type (e.g. `u32`), you can add `+ Into<u32>` to trait bounds of `T`, and use `let x: u32 = some_t_value.into()`. Does that help?

Comment: @user4815162342 Can't use `U: Into<T>` because there's no e.g. `impl Into<i32> for f32`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The initial thought might be to require `U:` [`Into<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html). However, there is no e.g. `impl Into<i32> for f32` so that won't work. Might also think of requiring `T:` [`Add<U, Output = T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), however that won't work in your case either for the same reason.

Instead you could use the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num), specifically the [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) trait.

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

// num = "0.3"
use num::cast::AsPrimitive;

fn sum<T, U>(x: T, y: U) -> T
where
    T: Copy + 'static,
    T: Add<Output = T>,
    U: AsPrimitive<T>,
{
    x + y.as_()
}
```

With that implementation of `sum()`, then executing your `main()` will output the following:

```
23
13.11
```